# How to solve unmatched column names/values in cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I am inserting a set of data in cassandra table .But i am getting un matched column names/values in there.i am posting the code and also the table structure

```
public static void aMethod2FromData(DetailsVO detailsVO) {

    System.out.println(detailsVO.getA_no());

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int num = (int) (Math.random() * 8847);
    int radar = (int) (Math.random() * 847);
    sb.append(
    "INSERT INTO CALL_RATIO_ANALYSYS (A_NO,JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUNE,JULY,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC,RADAR_VOICE,RADAR_SMS,RADAR_MMS,RADAR_GPRS,RADAR_OTHER,MMS_INCOMING,MMS_OUTGOING,VOICE_INCOING,VOICE_OUTGOING,SMS_INCOMING,SMS_OUTGOING,GPRS_SOCIAL,GPRS_MAIL,GPRS_GOOGLE,GPRS_ENTERTAINMENT,GPRS_BUSINESS)")
            .append("VALUES(");



        sb.append("'").append(detailsVO.getA_no()).append("',");
        //calculation for Jan to dec
        sb.append("'").append(num).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(num).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(num).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(num).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(num).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(num).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(num).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(num).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(num).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(num).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(num).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(num).append("',");
        //end here
        //start calculation of radar
        sb.append("'").append(radar).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(radar).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(radar).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(radar).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(radar).append("',");
        //ends here
        //mms incoming
        sb.append("'").append(radar).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(radar).append("',");
        //ends here
        //voice incoming outgoing
        sb.append("'").append(radar).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(radar).append("',");
        //end here
        //sms incoming outgoing
        sb.append("'").append(radar).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(radar).append("',");
        //ends here
        //gprs calculation 
        sb.append("'").append(radar).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(radar).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(radar).append("',");
        sb.append("'").append(radar).append("')");
        //ends here
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        String cql = sb.toString();
        session.execute(cql);
    }
```

this is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE CALL_RATIO_ANALYSYS(
A_NO TEXT,
JAN  TEXT,
FEB  TEXT,
MAR  TEXT,
APR  TEXT,
MAY  TEXT,
JUNE TEXT,
JULY TEXT,
AUG  TEXT,
SEP  TEXT,
OCT  TEXT,
NOV  TEXT,
DEC  TEXT,
RADAR_VOICE TEXT,
RADAR_SMS TEXT,
RADAR_MMS TEXT,
RADAR_GPRS TEXT,
RADAR_OTHER TEXT,
MMS_INCOMING TEXT,
MMS_OUTGOING TEXT,
VOICE_INCOMING TEXT,
VOICE_OUTGOING TEXT,
SMS_INCOMING TEXT,
SMS_OUTGOING TEXT,
GPRS_SOCIAL TEXT,
GPRS_MAIL TEXT,
GPRS_GOOGLE TEXT,
GPRS_ENTERTAINING TEXT,
GPRS_BUSINESS TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY(A_NO)
);
```

i can not understand where the column is not matching with the data please help

Comment: Afaik, cql3 is case insensitive by default unless you quote all stuff.

Comment: It helps if you post the error message you're getting.

Comment: I voted to close, I think you should show that you've done some minimal amount of work to try to understand the problem before you ask other people to count for you. If the computer tells you theres not enough values, count your values and see if they add up.

Comment: @Theo for me it helped. I am not a native English speaker and I thought 'unmatched column names/values' means that my column type does not match my value type. It would have saved me a lot of time if they would have told me that the number of parameters does not match.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you use prepared statements. It's not a direct solution to your problem, but you shouldn't build CQL statements like that. It's inefficient, and the code becomes a mess. There's probably a comma or something else missing, but trying to check the syntax of your code takes much more time than just rewriting it using prepared statements:

```
PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare("INSERT INTO CALL_RATIO_ANALYSYS (A_NO,JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUNE,JULY,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC,RADAR_VOICE,RADAR_SMS,RADAR_MMS,RADAR_GPRS,RADAR_OTHER,MMS_INCOMING,MMS_OUTGOING,VOICE_INCOING,VOICE_OUTGOING,SMS_INCOMING,SMS_OUTGOING,GPRS_SOCIAL,GPRS_MAIL,GPRS_GOOGLE,GPRS_ENTERTAINMENT,GPRS_BUSINESS) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
BoundStatement boundStatement = statement.bind(detailsVO.getA_no(), num, num, num, num, num, num, num, num, num, num, num, num, radar, radar, radar, radar, radar, radar, radar, radar, radar, radar, radar, radar, radar, radar, radar);
session.execute(boundStatement);
```

Keep the prepared statement around and re-use it.

**Edit** so the real problem here is that you're missing a value for the last parameter. If the error message says you have the wrong number of values, it helps if you count the values.

Comment: Although I encountered the "unmatched column/values" when developing a .NET application and I was creating the query by string concatenation (same amount of column/values, so no obvious mismatch), switching to prepared statements actually solved the issue on my side. Thank you, Theo!